# Add-Attachment wrapped in a method in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a service monitor, which checks along other values the http-Status of an http-request. All is working properly, but I am searching for smarter way for my code. 
The code I am using sends a mail with an attachment. However it would be nice, if I do not need to add the attachment-block to each if-statement.
I've searched for a possible solution, but as far as I've seen I can not create a method in a method. 
So...is there a way to avoid the additional lines of code? The attachment-block is evertime the same...

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

// define the class
class SendMailTLS {
    // define a method which recive your status code
    // instead of define main method
    public void sendMail(
    int httpStatus, ) {

        final String username = "sender@domain.com";
        final String password = "password";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender@domain.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("recipients@domain.com"));


            message.setSubject("Status alert - Service");
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            if (httpStatus == 200) {
                messageBodyPart.setText("OK! The http Status is: " + httpStatus);

                //////////// AttachmentBlock START//////////
                // Create a multipar message
                Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                // Set text message part
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                // Part two is attachment
                String attachmentPath = "c:\\doms\\log.txt";
                messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                FileDataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachmentPath);
                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                messageBodyPart.setFileName(source.getFile().getName());
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                // Send the complete message parts
                message.setContent(multipart);
                //////////// AttachmentBlock END////////// 

                Transport.send(message);
            }

            if (httpStatus != 200) {
                messageBodyPart.setText("ERROR! The http Status is: " + httpStatus);

                //////////// AttachmentBlock START//////////
                // Create a multipar message
                Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                // Set text message part
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                // Part two is attachment
                String attachmentPath = "c:\\doms\\log.txt";
                messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                FileDataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachmentPath);
                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                messageBodyPart.setFileName(source.getFile().getName());
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                // Send the complete message parts
                message.setContent(multipart);
                //////////// AttachmentBlock END////////// 

                Transport.send(message);
            }

            //Transport.send(message)
            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

// create new instance of your class
def mailSender = new SendMailTLS();
// send the mail passing the parameters
mailSender.sendMail(httpStatus);
```

Comment: Why can't you create a method that contains that block of code and call it each time instead of the whole block? Also you http codes aren't valid. You have the code 200 be the condition in two different if statements, one for a good request and one for a bad one

Comment: Create a private method outside of your `sendMail()` method and call it in `sendMail()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `private` method in your class that executes the block of code you need:

```
class SendMailTLS {

     // method that contains the attachment block
     private void sendAttachment(BodyPart messageBodyPart) {
        // Create a multipar message
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        // Set text message part
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        // Part two is attachment
        String attachmentPath = "c:\\doms\\log.txt";
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        FileDataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachmentPath);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(source.getFile().getName());
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        // Send the complete message parts
        message.setContent(multipart);
     }

     public void sendMail(
         int httpStatus, )

         // ... your code

         if (httpStatus == 200) {
            messageBodyPart.setText("OK! The http Status is: " + httpStatus);
            // execute the private method here and anywhere else you want the same code to run
            sendAttachment(messageBodyPart);
         }

         // ... rest of the code
     }
```

Also, as mentioned, your http codes aren't valid. You have the code 200 be the condition in two different if statements, one for a good request and one for a bad one. I assume you meant the second code to be one of the 400 range ones (Client error codes).

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I've tried it, but unfortunately this do not work for me. Because I am using this code-snipped within SoapUI, I'm not sure, if the error could also caused by SoapUI itself....The error is: _Missing propertyException: No such property: message for class: SendMailTLS_ The errors refers to the last line of the code...My code looks exactly like the follwoing: http://pastebin.com/uxCV59he
And yes...you're right ;) The doubled `httpStatus==200` was a typo.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Just so you know, you cannot execute code outside of a class in Java which is what you are trying to do in your pastebin (lines 92 - 98). However, I am not familiar with SoapUI, this is from a standard Java perspective.